# Move user to OU in Active Directory (Access is Denied Error)

Tags: .net, vb.net, active-directory

I am getting a `System.UnauthorizedAccessException {"Access is denied."}` error when I try to move a user to a different Organizational Unit within Active Directory.

Below is the code I am using. The error is thrown on the call to `MoveTo`. If I comment out the call to `MoveTo` then the user's telephone number updates successfully when `CommitChanges` is called, suggesting that is possibly not a permissions error.

Is anyone able to shed light on why I can't move the user to the new OU?

```
        Try

        Using Entry As DirectoryEntry = GetDirectoryEntry(DomainLogin) 'Retrieves the directory entry for the user.

            Entry.Properties("telephoneNumber").Value = "9999999" 'This successfully changes the user's phone number

            Dim strUserPass As String() = nBase.oAppControl.GetADUsernameAndPassword()

            'Create DirectoryEntry for the target OU
            Dim newLocation As DirectoryEntry = New DirectoryEntry("LDAP://testgrp.local/OU=Accounts,DC=local", strUserPass(0), strUserPass(1))

            Entry.MoveTo(newLocation) 'Throws exception
            Entry.CommitChanges()


            Return True

        End Using

    Catch ex As Exception
        Return False

    End Try
```

Comment: Are you sure the credentials passed in with `strUserPass` has the permissions to move a user?

Comment: Can you move the user via GUI? Like Active Directory Users And Computers console?

Comment: I will double check the permissions tomorrow and try via Windows too. The credentials for `strUserPass` allow the telephone number to be changed - is there a separate permission to move a user to an OU? Thanks for the responses

Comment: I get the `Access is Denied` when trying to move via the GUI, so it must be a permissions issue. Does anyone know the specific permission I need to allow me to move users across OUs?

Answer (score 0):

Although it's too late for your question, but for those who have the same issue , as I checked , The least privilege for moving user in OU is `Account Operator` .
for sure `Enterprise Admin` and `Domain Admin` has much more privilege.